# Is there a file search engine with a webserver?

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu, application, free-software

I connected a huge USB HD to my linux server. I installed samba and the files can now be accessed over network. I can search for files over network but the samba search is slow.

Do you know of any software that can index all the files and I just open a site in my browser and can search for that file? It can reindex the files database every night and it should be fast. It also would be nice to search inside files.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  [Recoll](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/) can regularly index your files and provide a search via your browser.  It can search within files too.

> Recoll is a full-text search tool for Unix and Linux desktops.
>
> Recoll finds keywords inside documents as well as file names.
>
> - It can search most document formats. You may need external applications for text extraction.
> - It can reach any storage place: files, archive members, email attachments, transparently handling decompression.
> - One click will open the document inside a native editor or display an even quicker text preview.
> - The software is free, open source, and licensed under the GPL.

If you did not require the "search via browser" option, a basic search is provided via the standard [updatedb](http://linux.die.net/man/8/updatedb) and [locate](http://linux.die.net/man/1/locate) commands.

Comment: Just a precision: the web interface is hosted separately from the main Recoll project. It is stored here: https://github.com/koniu/recoll-webui